# How do I ask for name/location permissions when using PHP fulfillment in DialogFlow?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

In DialogFlow, I have built an agent with the fulfillment webhook pointing to a PHP script. Now, I am at a point where I need to get the user's location.

I can see that on [this page about helpers](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#user_information), there are functions I can call to askForPermission or askForPermissions. Those work within the app framework if I build it in javascript with the *Actions on Google* framework.

Is there similar support for doing this from PHP? I can't find any documentation on it.

My fullfilments work like this currently, after calculating values for $speech, $displayText and $contextOut, each action concludes with:

```
$response = Array(
  'speech' => $speech,
  'displayText' => $displayText,
  'contextOut' => $contextOut    // when necessary
);

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

I'm thinking I need to attach a 'data' element to that $response, but what's the syntax to trigger the permissions request?

Comment: Can you update your question to illustrate how you are sending the reply currently? (It will make it easier to illustrate how to reply to prompt for the permission.)

Comment: @Prisoner, updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, you'll need to attach a "data" element which contains nested elements with the request information. This is documented if you click on the JSON tab where the [helper is documented](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#json), but that is also if you're using the Action SDK. If you're using Dialogflow (which it looks like you are) then your reply needs to be modified a little.

You will need to add both a [richResponse](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#richresponse) containing a dummy text response, along with a [systemIntent](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#ExpectedIntent) object containing the permission request. It will need to be something like this:

```
$response = Array(
  'speech' => 'PLACEHOLDER',
  'data' => Array(
    'google' => Array(
      'richResponse' => Array(
        'items' => Array(
          Array(
            'simpleResponse' => Array(
              'textToSpeech' => 'PLACEHOLDER'
            )
          )
        )
      ),
      'systemIntent' => Array(
        'intent' => 'actions.intent.PERMISSION',
        'data' => Array(
          '@type' => 'type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.PermissionValueSpec',
          'optContext' => 'To locate you',
          'permissions' => Array(
            'DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION'
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
);
```